# Trying to activate an nginx website on Raspbian on port 8000

Tags: nginx, raspberry-pi, webserver, port, raspbian

I've managed to install nginx and bring up a website on port 81 (port 80 is blocked by my isp).  I am trying to enable a second website on port 8000 with someone elses code.  My test website was much simpler as I only had to put:

```
server  {
        listen 81;
        root /var/www;
        index index.html;
}
```

If I go to [http://127.0.0.1:81] in a browser, I will get the above website.

The second website is a bit more complicated and I'm not getting nginx to forward requests on port 8000.  I have the second website in /var/www/website2.  If I type [http://127.0.0.1:8000], I get "page not found.  However, if I type [http://127.0.0.1:81/website2], then I get the website.

I have both sites available and enabled and I have a website2.cfg file located in /etc/nginx/.

Here is the content of the website2 file located in sites-available:

```
server {

    server_name localhost;

    auth_basic "Private Site";
    auth_basic_user_file .htpasswd;

    location / {
        root /var/www;
        index index.html ;
    }

    location /captures/ {
        root /var/www;
    }

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location /video {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8002;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

Here is the content of the website2.cfg file located in /etc/nginx/:

```
[DEFAULT]
# Root directory of the service
root=/var/www/website2

[main]
logFile = /var/log/website2/website2.log

[web]
# Relative URL path to the captured images. Must match what is configurd in nginx, which much
match the directory specified in the [camera] section
capturePath=/captures

# Port on which the web server will listen
port=8000

[camera]

# The number of captured images to retain before pruning old ones
capturesToRetain=100

# The directory to store captured images. Please make sure this matches what was specified in the 
[web] section
captureDir=%(root)s/captures

# The port on which the motion program listens for HTTP commands
motionControlPort = 8001

# The port on which the motion program streams video
motionStreamPort = 8002
```

If I can get this website serving on port 8000, I should be able to get the rest of the site working.  Any help would be appreciated.